# Importing typescript files for Angular project in node server

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ts-node

I am unable to import TS files that exist in my Angular project directories inside my Node server.

I've looked into various settings for a `tsconfig.json` file for the Node server specifically but have had no luck.

I run my node server via `npm start` like so `"start": "nodemon --exec ts-node -- ./start.ts"`

My project structure looks something like this...

```
....
node_modules/
src/
  app/
    shared/
      models/
        entity.model.ts
stub-server/
  start.ts
  src/
    data/
      entity-data.ts
angular.json
tsconfig.json
...
```

I expect to be able to import the relevent Typescript classes/interfaces/enums etc from `entity.model.ts` inside `entity-data.ts` so that I can enforce type safety within my mocked data.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to use better tooling for your project.
Please check https://nx.dev/ and create your Angular app and Node app, move your code there, and then you will be able to create a library with your shared stuff, to be imported from both projects.

Nx will take care of the configuration and the tsconfig paths required to make it work. And talking about `tsconfig.paths`, you may try to setup one in your current project, perhaps this structure is not clean:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "paths": {
    "@shared/*": ["src/app/shared/*"]
  }
}
```

and import your stuff from your server like

```
import { MyModel } from '@shared/models';
```

Anyways, consider the migration of your code to Nx and you will be able to enjoy a clean architecture and workflow. Happy coding!

Comment: While I appreciate the comment, NX isn't appropriate for our projects as we aren't interesting in monolithic repos at this point in our organization. Plus our node app isn't for production it is simply a dev server to use rather than our Java BE for local development.

That being said, the following solution isn't working unfortunately.